# When connecting a MongoDB client to a MongoDB server, I get: 'Couldn't connect to server'

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mongodb

I am just learning MongoDB, and I tried to connect one of my machines (the client) to the server (which is a [Toshiba L875D](http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/L870/L875D-S7332)).

The server is running Windows 8.1 and the client Windows 7.

Here is a client screenshot:

[image]

I also tried `0.0.0.0` as the IP address and got the same error.

Here is a server screenshot:

[image]

I am trying to make this connection over a Wi-Fi network.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry. I have now added that.

Comment: Hi @nicholas Brown can u please provide the solution of above problem? Because i am also  facing same problem while i am connecting to another system in a network thanks.

Comment: @tarun Hi. JakeGould's solution below worked. If you're using an API to connect to the database, you shouldn't have to open up MongoDB to outside connections like I was trying to, though.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely still have the `bind_ip` on your MongoDB server set to `127.0.0.1` which would only allow you to connect to it on the server via `localhost`. To enable networking—so another machine other that a `localhost` connection can connect to the setup—the MongoDB config on the server needs to be adjusted so the `bind_ip` setting option is disabled.

First, open up the `mongod.conf` on the server it’s installed. I am showing an example using `nano` in Linux but feel free to edit that file with whatever editor you feel most comfortable using. And if you are editing this on Windows, you would need to find and adjust the `mongod.cfg` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

With that file open for editing, find this line:

```
# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

And comment out the `bind_ip` like this:

```
# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Now restart MongDB:

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Networking should be enabled and you should be able to connect to it from any other machine on your network.

Comment: I can't find a configuration file. I used mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 on the server and it gave me a warning saying that isn't necessary, and that it listens on all IPs by default.

Comment: It looks as if it doesn't create a cfg file in Windows unless the user creates it themselves.